# Not able to send mail using mail() php?

Tags: php

I am  Not able to send mail with This Code  ?

**CODE :**

```
<?php
// the message
$msg = "Thank You";

// send email
echo mail("*****@gmail.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

Comment: i have use echo to see `mail()` is working or not . now tell me how echo can create the problam

Comment: i am not saying it will create problem i just said don't need to use echo there also i asked for environment means local or server because many time it is also important in this scenario because you just posted "Not able to send mail using mail() " with no error description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `wordwrap();`

```
 $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
```

Comment: $msg has 7 letters this function won't even work on $msg because it's length should be more than 70 characters. Also I don't see how this could help OP.

Comment: Can you explain why? Because `echo (int)(wordwrap($msg, 70) === $msg);` is true so both strings are the same and function does nothing on $msg string

Comment: Some times its works . I also face the almost same problem before  . May be thats why it works

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you don't have your mail server configured. Try to do it in php.ini or install mail catcher. For example: http://mailcatcher.me/

Also check http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

There may be several answers for that :

- If you are on a local server, maybe your mail server isn't configured
- If you are on a shared host, the function may have been deactivated.

What's the return of the mail() function ?

Comment: it's blank screen because it returns false. if you do `echo (int)mail("*****@gmail.com","My subject",$msg);` it will output `0` so check my answer and do things I mentioned there

Comment: mail() function only returns boolean values. You'll have to var_dump them : var_dump(mail("*****@gmail.com","My subject",$msg));

Comment: Thanks A lot .. I have Tried `wordwrap()` and its working fine .